# Stop execution of batch file on error for sqlplus in oracle

Tags: database, oracle, oracle10g, sqlplus, database-agnostic

I am having 4 files named
test.bat which contains

```
@echo off
C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\10.2.0\server\BIN\sqlplus -s -l user/pass@localhost @E:\Oracle_Files\query.sql>E:\Oracle_Files\error.txt;
C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\10.2.0\server\BIN\sqlplus -s -l user/pass@localhost @E:\Oracle_Files\query1.sql>E:\Oracle_Files\error.txt
```

Now query.sql contains

```
WHENEVER SQLERROR EXIT SQL.SQLCODE
insert into mytable12 values('d');
exit;
```

And query1.sql contains

```
WHENEVER SQLERROR EXIT SQL.SQLCODE
begin
insert into mytable1 values('d2');
end;
exit;
```

Now the problem is REAL TABLE NAME is mytable1,so here problem is I want to stop execution of batch file as soon as error came below scripts on error should not get executed, and also on error `errorlog.txt` file content gets replaced with "`1 row updated`" that means my previous error message are getting overwrite, how can I stop this ?

In short there are 2 issues

- how to stop further execution of scripts on error in particular 1    script file.
- How to prevent from overwriting of logs in log file

Comment: For issue with overwritten logs , you may need to replace the `>` with `>>` which will append the content and not overwrite.

Comment: Ok in that case this message is getting print :                 insert into mytable12 values('final1')
            *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist



1 row created.
But now the problem is I dont want 1 row created success message only if error message is there then it should write..what could be done for that??

Comment: set feedback off; will not display 1 row created. But I beleive cant you do a pl/sql with utl_file instead? if you want a better control of how to handle things.

Comment: also one more thing how to clear contents of log file before start?

Comment: run ur first script with '>' as log redirection. it automatically creates a empty file and overwrites..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to check the errorlevel after each call to SQL*Plus

```
@echo off
C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\10.2.0\server\BIN\sqlplus -s -l user/pass@localhost @E:\Oracle_Files\query.sql>E:\Oracle_Files\error.txt;
if errorlevel 1 (
  goto error
)
C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\10.2.0\server\BIN\sqlplus -s -l user/pass@localhost @E:\Oracle_Files\query1.sql>>E:\Oracle_Files\error.txt
    if errorlevel 1 (
      goto error
    )
:: no error, skip error message
    goto end
    :error
      echo error occurred - check log file
    :end
```

Comment: If you check for errorlevel 1, you will have to make sure sqlplus exit with value 1: whenever sqlerror exit 1; I think this is platform dependent.

Comment: Based on the @echo off and the use of Oracle XE.  I feel pretty sure that it's on Windows.  The check for errorlevel 1 will pick up errorlevel values of 1 or greater.

Comment: Ok in that case this message is getting print : insert into mytable12 values('final1') * ERROR at line 1: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist 1 row created. But now the problem is I dont want 1 row created success message only if error message is there then it should write..what could be done for that??

Comment: Add "set termout off" at the beginning of your SQL script. (without the quotes)